# Processing and Merging files before uploading them to Amazon S3

Tags: meteor, file-upload, amazon-s3, merge, meteor-slingshot

I'm developing a web platform using meteorjs that will allows me to upload multiple text/plain such as .txt and .csv files to my amazon S3 bucket.

Currently my platform supports multiple files uploads, uploading them  sequentially by using a for loop and meteor-slingshot to upload to my s3 directly.

**What I'm trying to do:**
I need to merge the files into one final file before the uploading to S3  happens so I can upload just one file instead of uploading multiple files (Files must be merged in one).

**My ideas:**

1. I've thought about uploading the files into my own server before they're uploaded to S3 and then use something like `cat file1.txt file2.txt > merged_file.txt` in linux to merge them and retrieve this file somehow, but it'll take longer because we need to upload the files to my server and then upload the merged file to the S3 bucket.
2. Use the `fs.appendFile` from node to merge the files, but I don't know if it could be viable because files can be up to 20/25mb and it'll will take some time to read them and append the information.

I think javascript is not probably viable to handle this directly, that's why I'm thinking in sh commands or c++ because of the nodejs core.

Can you recommend me a better way of doing this?
is there a better way to handle this process?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily in shell.

`for i in file1 file2 file3
do
cat $i >> combined_file
done`

I would also say that you might want to consider uploading them as small files and then spin up an aws instance pull them down, merge them, and re-upload them.  that way you don't lose the originals and it you can automate this whole process.

Comment: you mean upload the files to my own server, then run the cat command and upload the final file to my s3 bucket? btw thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: No, I mean uploading the unmerged files to `bucket-a` then spinning up an EC2 instance to download and merge the files from `bucket-a` then uploading them to `bucket-b`

Comment: What if I wanna do this before the uploading process happens, I mean can I do this with meteor using sh or node in some way?

Comment: yes, you can do this in node or sh.  Can you talk more about why they need to be combined into one upload?

Comment: because one user can upload multiple mail lists to merge them into one mail list and compare it against suppressions lists to clean the merged file. sort of what Send-Safe Email List Manager does. [Here a link to the software](http://www.send-safe.com/list-manager.html)

Comment: can you give me a hint of how to do it with sh?, do I need to upload the file to my server first in order to process the files uploaded by the user and then uploade it to s3?

Comment: You would upload them to your server.  Then combine the files on the server,  then upload them to S3.

Comment: Ok, my proposition #1 is the best way to go for now then.